# Can't update via composer because of lock file

Tags: 8, composer

I am trying to install Lightning 8.1.0. I am currently at 8.1.00-rc5. When I run `composer require drupal/lightning:8.1.0` I get the following response:

```
± |master ✓| → composer require drupal/lightning:8.1.0
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    1/1:  http://packagist.org/p/provider-latest$aa4f1da6acef0b15640bc1cace21327f5342dbb88c61b4605f0b1b0ff21d7399.json
    Finished: success: 1, skipped: 0, failure: 0, total: 1
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: drupal/entity_browser[8.1.x-dev, 8.1.0-alpha3].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/entity_browser[8.1.0-alpha3, 8.1.x-dev].
    - drupal/lightning 8.1.00 requires drupal/entity_browser 8.1.0-alpha3 -> satisfiable by drupal/entity_browser[8.1.0-alpha3].
    - Installation request for drupal/lightning 8.1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/lightning[8.1.00].
    - Installation request for drupal/entity_browser (locked at 8.1.x-dev) -> satisfiable by drupal/entity_browser[8.1.x-dev].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

The only way I get around this is that I have to remove the composer.lock file before I run `composer require drupal/lightning:8.1.0`. Does this sound like the right way to do it?

- composer.json: http://pasted.co/f2561b5d
- composer.lock: http://pasted.co/573a945e

Comment: You only need to do `composer require` if you are adding a dependency to your application. You probably are thinking of `composer update drupal/lightning:8.1.0` if I recall correctly.

Comment: If I run `composer update drupal/lightning:8.1.0` I get Package "drupal/lightning:8.1.0" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.

Comment: Delete the lock file and run `composer install` again.

Comment: If the above doesn't work then you should attach your computer.json file above.

Comment: @Eyal I added links to the files.

Comment: Remove the `drupal/entity_browser` line. Remove the computer.lock file. And try to run composer install

Comment: @Eyal  Thanks! It does work when removing the lock file but I thought that is the wrong way.

Comment: The lock file is only needed for deployment. To make sure the production server will have the exact same packages as the development server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I updated is I manually updated composer and set Lightning to 8.1.0 and then ran `composer update drupal/lightning`.

Comment: This is the right way :)

Comment: @Chapabu Do you think there is a way to do this via composer command?   Some kind of force flag or something like that.

Comment: If you set the version for Lightning to `8.1.*` then running `composer update` will get the latest patch release if one is available.

Comment: @Chapabu What about if I have the full version inside my composer file already.  Reason I do that is that I want all my sites to always be at the same version.

Comment: What do you mean you have the full version in your composer file already? If you change `8.1.0` to `8.1.*` you'll still be getting the full version, it'll just be the latest patch release (depending on your `minimum-stability`).

Comment: But what if I have 8.1.0 in my composer and I want to update to 8.1.2. The only way would be to update the composer file to 8.1.2 or 8.1.*.  I'm inclined to use the full version (8.1.2 instead of 8.1.*) because I want every single site to have the same version. Let me know if you think that is bad?

Comment: `8.1.*` IS the full version, it just the latest patch release.

Comment: This might be of use: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md

Comment: @albertski if you want to do this without manually editing you composer.json file, just pass the `--no-update` flag to your composer require command. Then run `composer update` afterwards: `composer require drupal/lightning:8.1.13 --no-update`. Then `composer update`

Answer (score 3):

If you're dealing with a top level dependency, you can remove the old version and then install the new version:

```
composer remove drupal/lightning
composer require drupal/lightning:8.1.0
```

Comment: Oh yeah! I was simply trying to `composer require provision-ops/yaml-tests` to upgrade it and kept getting dependency issues even though that was the only package that was requiring things. Composer didn't tell me which package only that the problem package was "locked at 1.7.1" or something like that. Your technique worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case due to security reasons on a GitHub repository.

I solved updating the dependency to a specific version like this:

```
composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:2.0.31
```

If you are working with virtual environments like docker containers (ddev, lando, etc..) before running it you should connect to the container with a:

```
ddev ssh
```